# Bound on Jensen's gap for bivariate functions

Tags: probability, statistics, functions, jensen-inequality, bivariate-distributions

I have recently been reading on Jensen's gap for univariate functions. Specifically, [here, page 6, Theorem 2.1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.05267.pdf), an upper bound on Jensen's gap is provided that is based on absolute central moments. I was wondering if there are any extensions to the bivariate case, i.e., $f:R^2 \rightarrow R$ in the mentioned theorem. Assume $x$ and $y$ are the inputs to the function $f$ with means $\mu_x$, $\mu_y$, and variances $\sigma^2_x$, $\sigma^2_y$ and covariance $\sigma_{xy}$. I thought if I replace the conditions 2 and 3 respectively with:
$$|f(x,y)-f(\mu_x, \mu_y)| =O(|(x-\mu_x)(y-\mu_y)|^\alpha), \qquad \alpha>0$$
and
$$|f(x,y)| =O(|xy|^n), \qquad n\geq\alpha$$
and define
$$M=\text{sup} \frac{|f(x,y)-f(\mu_x, \mu_y)|}{|(x-\mu_x)(y-\mu_y)|^\alpha + |(x-\mu_x)(y-\mu_y)|^n}$$
would do the job, but it didn't! Appreciate your time!